# Querying another DB while connecting to other Database in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005

In my SQL script I am using one database(Lets assume **MyDb1**).

In side that script I need to query `extended property` of another DB (**MyDb2**).
I have no Idea  to do this.

Please advise me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Query :

```
SELECT * FROM MyDb1.DBO.TableName as tbl1,MyDb2.DBO.TableName as tbl2
WHERE tbl1.ID=tbl2.ID
```